# How to find NOT NULL columns by union?

Tags: mysql

I have three table as:

1.table person

```
id, others
1, x
2, y
3, z
4, w
```

2.table followup, FOREIGN KEY (`person_id`) REFERENCES `person` (`id`)

```
id, person_id, ftime, details
1, 1, '2018-01-12', 'json_1'
2, 1, '2018-04-21', 'json_2'
3, 2, '2017-12-16', 'json_3'
4, 2, '2018-01-17', NULL
5, 3, '2018-06-02', 'json_5'
6, 4, '2018-01-19', NULL
```

3.table followup_track, FOREIGN KEY (`fid`) REFERENCES `followup` (`id`)

```
id, fid, ftime, details
1, 1, '2018-01-27', 't_json_1'
2, 2, '2018-05-07', 't_json_2'
3, 5, '2018-06-17', 't_json_3'
```

Now I want find all the last ftime of every person, and the details IS NOT NULL in followup and/or followup_track.

the result what I want to get is (here the pid is person's id):

```
pid, ftime, details
1, '2018-05-07', 't_json_2'
2, '2017-12-16', 'json_3'
3, '2018-06-17', 't_json_3'
```

Because there is no detalis != NULL for person.id = 4, so the result no need for pid=4.

Because the last time of person.id = 1 is '2018-05-07', so need that column.

I create a view like:

```
CREATE VIEW view_full_flup AS
SELECT
  p.id AS pid, fp.ftime, fp.details
FROM
  ((followup_track fp
    LEFT JOIN followup ON (fp.fid = followup.id))
    LEFT JOIN person p ON (followup.person_id = p.id))
WHERE
  fp.details IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT
  f.person_id AS pid, f.ftime, f.details
FROM
  followup f
WHERE
  f.details IS NOT NULL
```

Then, I use sql:

```
     SELECT *, MAX(`ftime`) FROM view_full_flup GROUP BY pid;
```

Is my solution right please? The details can not make index, and it is slow. How to do this right please?

Comment: i assume you cannot modify your tables, right? cause one of the first things that i believe would make your query easier and faster, involves modifying that structure.

Comment: @Erubiel Thank you. Yes I can not modify my tables, just can create some views.

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: @scaisEdge sorry. I put some datas and results just now.

Answer (score 0):

You can’t select star group by(well, you might be able to in MySQL depending on how it’s set up but it’s not a great habit to get into for portability of sql skills), you have to specify a list of columns in your select and either group them (put the column name in the group by) or aggregate them (pass the column name into an aggregate function)

It feels like you’ve got your left join logic backwards- person is the only table you know you have records in, so it should be on the left side of the join.. the other tables are potentially recordless

We’re this my query I’d write it something more like:

```
select
  Pid,
  Max(case when ft.ftime > f.ftime then ft.ftime else f.ftime end) maxft
From
  Person p
  Left join (select * from followup where details is not null) f on f.person_id = p.id
  Left join (select * from follup_track where details is not null) ft on ft.fid = f.id
Group by pid
```

We just join the set of tables once, having already filtered for records where either table’s details are present and then get the max date from either table

Note that this query can return null dates, if you have records where the date column is null even though details is filled in. If those are undesirable, filter hem with a HAVING or wrap the whole thing in another select and filter using a WHERE

Ps; as it stands, this query doesn’t seem particularly useful because though you know the most recent date you don’t have any other data. If it’s all you wanted to know (I wasn’t able to tell from your original post because the description and the query disagreed in what they said they wanted) then great, but if you wanted the other info, maybe using mysql 8’s new analytic queries would better suit:

```
Select * from
(
 select
  Pid,
  Row_number over(partition by pid order by (case when ft.ftime > f.ftime then ft.ftime else f.ftime end) desc) rown 
 From
  Person p
  Left join (select * from followup where details is not null) f on f.person_id = p.id
  Left join (select * from follup_track where details is not null) ft on ft.fid = f.id
) a where rown = 1
```

Comment: Thank you. If some person has no followup, I do not need the details. If the person has followup (with details is not null), but has no followup_track, I just need the details of the followup. the person's count ~ 3500, and every year, we have 4 followup for every person, then, maybe 2 (mayby 0) followup_track for every followup.

Comment: So are you querying the database for a particular person each time, or producing a report for all persons?

Comment: from Wednesday to Saturday, 45 - 90 people will be queried everyday, other times ~30 people per day. but the people are different each week.

Comment: So on Wednesday are you going to run the query 45 times with one person ID in the query each time, or are you wanting to run the report once and have it produce an output that contains 45 people?

Comment: On Wednesday, the staff will have to follow up 45 people at least, these people are randomly. Now I think, maybe I need a procedure, so it just find the ftime, details by 45 ids. is it the right way?

Comment: I’m asking because it’s relatively easy to do a report for a single person, and do it 45 times. It’s a bit harder to have a report that chooses 45 random people and pulls their details do you have a UI that you’re building this into?

Comment: On Wednesday, the staff will call some people, if the people at home, then put ftime, details into a list, until the list has 45-90 people. Then print the list, the staff will follow up these people by the list, record some info, and back to update the ftime, details. Next time(in one quarter, must one(allow many) time for every people.) the staff ignore these people, find other 45-90 people.

Comment: I create a procedure, the staff can call it 45 times by 45 person's ids:

CREATE PROCEDURE get_last_details(IN pid int)
BEGIN
  SELECT
    ftime, details
  FROM
    followup
  WHERE
    person_id = pid AND details IS NOT NULL
  UNION
  SELECT
    ft.ftime, ft.details
  FROM
    followup_track AS ft
      LEFT JOIN followup AS f ON ft.fid = f.id
      LEFT JOIN person AS p ON f.person_id = p.id
  WHERE
    f.person_id = pid AND ft.details IS NOT NULL
  ORDER BY ftime DESC;
END;